# constant value '-1025' cannot be converted to `ushort`

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains a functions that needs to set and clear a bit field value.The code is given below. In line

`FlagsValues &= ~(UInt16)EFlagsValues.NIn;`

below I get the error saying that constant value '-1025' cannot be converted to `ushort`

What is wrong with my code and why am I getting this error.?

```
public class MySetupC 
    {

            private UInt16 m_FlagsValues;
            private UInt16 m_FlagsMask;

            public UInt16 FlagsMask { get { return m_FlagsMask; } private set { m_FlagsMask = value; } }
            public UInt16 FlagsValues { get { return m_FlagsValues; } private set { m_FlagsValues = value; } }

            [Flags]
            public enum EFlagsMask
            {
                None = 0,
                AIn = (1 << 0),  //1
                BIn = (1 << 1),  //2
                CIn = (1 << 2),  //4 
                DIn = (1 << 3), //8
                EIn = (1 << 4),  //16
                FIn = (1 << 5),  //32
                JIn = (1 << 6),
                KIn = (1 << 7),
                LIn = (1 << 8),
                MIn = (1 << 9),
                NIn = (1 << 10),
                OIn = (1 << 11),
            }

            [Flags]
            public enum EFlagsMask
            {
                None = 0,
                AIn = (1 << 0),  //1
                BIn = (1 << 1),  //2
                CIn = (1 << 2),  //4 
                DIn = (1 << 3), //8
                EIn = (1 << 4),  //16
                FIn = (1 << 5),  //32
                JIn = (1 << 6),
                KIn = (1 << 7),
                LIn = (1 << 8),
                MIn = (1 << 9),
                NIn = (1 << 10),
                OIn = (1 << 11),
            }

        public void SetNIn(bool enable)
        {
            if (enable)
            {
                FlagsValues |= (UInt16)EFlagsValues.NIn;
                FlagsMask |= (UInt16)EFlagsMask.NIn;
            }
            else
            {
                //negate
                FlagsValues &= ~(UInt16)EFlagsValues.NIn;
                FlagsMask |= (UInt16)EFlagsMask.NIn;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1 << 10 is giving you 1024. The ~ is turning that into -1025 which is not unsigned.

Comment: I just want to clear bit 10 without touching other bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive your enum from UInt16

```
public enum EFlagsMask : UInt16 {
```

Then, do your ~ operator on the enum value, not the UInt16;

```
FlagsValues &= (UInt16)~EFlagsMask.NIn;
```